# SUM in MySQL select statement getting incremented

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT                      
SUM(er.total)    
AS total
FROM    
campaigns AS cmp    
JOIN versions AS cv ON (cv.campaign_id = cmp.id)
JOIN creatives AS cr ON (cr.version_id = cv.id)
JOIN records AS er ON (er.creative_id = cr.id)
WHERE    
cmp.business_id IN (-1,'39909') AND
cv.campaign_id IN (-1,65288) AND
er.type IN (5,6,1) AND    
er.date BETWEEN '2017-06-11' AND '2017-06-11'    
GROUP BY version_id, er.date
```

I need to add one new condition in where clause, for which it requires to add new join, like this -

```
    SELECT                      
    SUM(er.total)    
    AS total
    FROM    
    campaigns AS cmp
    JOIN products as p ON (p.campaign_id = cmp.id)
    JOIN versions AS cv ON (cv.campaign_id = cmp.id)
    JOIN creatives AS cr ON (cr.version_id = cv.id)
    JOIN records AS er ON (er.creative_id = cr.id)
    WHERE    
    cmp.business_id IN (-1,'39909') AND
    cv.campaign_id IN (-1,65288) AND
    er.type IN (5,6,1) AND    
    er.date BETWEEN '2017-06-11' AND '2017-06-11' AND
    p.product_id IN(1,2)
    GROUP BY version_id, er.date
```

But, here, value for `SUM(er.total)` gets changed, it gets incremented. I tried it with adding left / right / inner joins. But result is same. How should I add join for this table without getting total incremented?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT                      
    SUM(er.total)    
    AS total
    FROM    
    campaigns AS cmp
    JOIN products as p ON (p.campaign_id = cmp.id and p.product_id IN(1,2))
    JOIN versions AS cv ON (cv.campaign_id = cmp.id)
    JOIN creatives AS cr ON (cr.version_id = cv.id)
    JOIN records AS er ON (er.creative_id = cr.id)
    WHERE    
    cmp.business_id IN (-1,'39909') AND
    cv.campaign_id IN (-1,65288) AND
    er.type IN (5,6,1) AND    
    er.date BETWEEN '2017-06-11' AND '2017-06-11' AND

    GROUP BY version_id, er.date
```

Try above query.

Here I had made changes from putting that condition `ON` clause instead of `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But not worked. Getting incremented sum.